# Scala url path parameter parser

Tags: scala

is there a library in scala that will parse url path paramters

for example

```
val url = "http://example.com/items/:id"
val reqUrl = "http://example.com/itmes/23"
val pathParams = SomeUrlLibrary.parse(url, reqUrl)
```

where pathParams is `Map("id" -> 23)`

Comment: Maybe look at [http4s](http://http4s.org/).

Comment: I was checking it out earlier today.  I'm asking specifically for just this functionality and not a complete solution though.

Comment: It appears that what I'm looking for is something like Spring's URI template.  Where I can use the match method to get a map of parameters and values.  Can I get that dependency without downloading the entire spring framework?

Comment: I suppose it may be simpler to just write a function that will do this job for you. If your only case is params separated with `/`, prefixed with `:`, then it should be straightforward. Otherwise lib will not help you much, as it supports probably one pattern at the time, and they usually are for putting in, not extracting params.